# Particle annihilation - mathematical description, equations governing it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I was wondering about this and I would like to know an explanation why do particles and antiparticles annihilate? I would be interested in phenomenological, but most importantly mathematic explanation of annihilation. Do we even have a complete mathematic description of the phenomenon?

I am asking if there is an equation, like in Newtonian mechanics that governs elastic and non-elastic collisions of massive bodies(not particles, just two massive balls) or equations that govern deformation. There is no answer giving a sufficient information about MATHEMATICAL description.

Comment: please look at http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190463/ where I have recently answered the same question

Comment: @annav Sorry, but I am not asking about the description of annihilation process by feynmann diagrams, I am asking mainly about mathematical description. I mean if there is an equation that governs annihilation.

Comment: @user74200: [Feynmann diagrams *are* mathematical expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram), just in pictorial form.

Comment: As Kylle says, there exists a one to one correspondance of Feynman diagrams with rules and  formulae, integrals that give crossections for the interactions described pictorially.  http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/FeyAlgGeomShort.pdf  and https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~dduke/devoto-duke-84.pdf